# I get an error while running nativescript

Tags: nativescript-angular

I get this error when ever I try to run android

> Unable to apply changes on device: 037440992E015901.
>   Error is: zlib: unexpected end of file. ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir
>   'C:\Users\Hazin\AppData\Local\Temp\runtimeDir119530-8496-2dkhiq.wv07n\framework\build-tools'

Comment: Without the code producing the error, I don't think that many people can help you. If you want you can check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maybe improve your question and get a solid picture of what's wrong. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps.

1. Delete temp file in your system.
2. Then clean your app - remove the ./node_modules, ./hooks and ./platforms folders again install npm and add platform. (Type this command in project directory for remove folders:- **rm -rf node_modules/hooks/platforms**)
3. And try to run the app again.